# Google Colaboratory - Llama Index : Address already in use when trying to load Google Doc

Tags: google-colaboratory, google-docs, google-docs-api, openai-api, llama-index

I'm trying to connect google collab using llama-index & openai library and google doc.

Following exactly the same example from the doc: https://llamahub.ai/l/google_docs .

The code I'm running, after installing libraries.

```
from llama_index import GPTSimpleVectorIndex, download_loader
OPENAI_API_KEY = "abc"

GoogleDocsReader = download_loader('GoogleDocsReader')

gdoc_ids = ['abc']
loader = GoogleDocsReader()
documents = loader.load_data(document_ids=gdoc_ids)
```

I uploaded the credentials.json file as recommended in the doc in:

```
/content/credentials.json
```

The credentials.json downloaded as explained in the doc https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials#api-key is structured as follow:

```
{"installed":{"client_id":"xyz.apps.googleusercontent.com","project_id":"myprojctId","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","client_secret":"abc","redirect_uris":["http://localhost"]}}
```

When I'm running the script I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError Traceback (most recent call last)
in
17 gdoc_ids = ['abc']
18 loader = GoogleDocsReader()
---> 19 documents = loader.load_data(document_ids=gdoc_ids)
20 index = GPTSimpleVectorIndex(documents)

8 frames
/usr/lib/python3.9/socketserver.py in server_bind(self)
464 if self.allow_reuse_address:
465 self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
--> 466 self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
467 self.server_address = self.socket.getsockname()
468

OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that llama_hub is using this Python code to authenticate against Google Drive:

`/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/llama_hub/google_docs/base.py`

```
 flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                    "credentials.json", SCOPES
                )
                creds = flow.run_local_server(port=8080)
```

As you can see, the code tries to open a local server listening in `tcp/8080`. I think that it is needed for completing the OAuth incantation (a callback URL). But either that port is already binded or it is not possible to do that in Colab. I ended up running the code locally. Once you do it locally, you'll get a `token.json` file that you can upload to Google Colab and continue from there.